# Can I deploy to production without validating my change set?

Tags: unit-test, deployment, change-set

Am I able to deploy an inbound change set to production without validating it?

I know it is best practice but I can't get the unit test to work as I am getting the following error in my test.

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

The code if working fine though, I have been testing manually.

Thanks.

[FYI this is a link to my code (on the SFDC developer's forum)](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G0000005mx7QAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The act of deploying a changeset, if it involves apex code, will run your tests and hence will be validated. If you are having a null pointer exception, then you won't be able to deploy as the tests will fail.

Validation *per se* is merely the step of running the tests but not deploying. Validated change sets can be deployed later in time.